# Taking part of the PayPal transaction fee

Tags: payments, software

I create free software plugins which people can install on their website. This software allows them to integrate PayPal into their website so they can sell products.

I was recently watching an older episode of Shark Tank and was interested in the pitch from honeyfund.com. During the pitch the company says that they worked out a deal with PayPal so that their customers pay the standard transaction fee of 2.9% + .30, but they get a small percent of that because of their high volume.

They mentioned a few numbers and doing the math it works out to PayPal paying them 1.495% of all transactions.

I am not sure what PayPal's definition of high volume is, but my plugins are installed on thousands of website. If I could make a small percent of all the transactions that occur, that would be amazing.

Can anyone please explain how I can work out this type of relationship with PayPal.

Comment: err.. contact Paypal.

Comment: Why would you downvote this? Is it not apparent I wanted to ask others before contacting PayPal? This is why this community is worthless.

Comment: The only **definitive** answer to this would come directly from PayPal. Not a bunch of random people on the internet. StackExchange sites may be unlike other sites you are accustomed to. SE sites are *not* discussion forums. They are geared around a strict question<>answer format. Since *only* PayPal can answer this question for you, it's clear no effort to solve the issue on your own has been taken, thus the down vote.

Comment: You can hope that someone here uses Paypal in the same way as you hope they do. So they may answer eventually. But as Scott says, I would also ask Paypal. If it's their public policy, they will gladly explain how you can apply to get a portion of it.

Comment: I disagree, if you had a problem with a Google Maps API you wouldn't email Google. Same here. With supportive communities its much more efficient and faster to get the answer you are looking for then to contact a mega corp and wait a few days for a reply. If someone is unable to answer the question, you don't downvote it or say to contact PayPal. Obviously I would have contacted them already if I felt that was the best option.

Comment: A technical problem with an API is nowhere near the same as a financial agreement with a corporation. What would you expect people to answer here other than "contact Paypal"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paypal offer special rates for partners, but it's worth looking at their [merchant rates](https://www.paypal.com/uk/merchantrate) first. I think you have to exceed £55k monthly for them to consider you for a partnership... but even then, their merchant rates are pretty fair.

You'll definitely have to get in touch with them sooner or later but it's well worth a shot... the worst they can do is say no. Although if you are successful then it's more ultimately more money for them!

Also, (not directly related to your question but it's nice to know there are other options available) it might be worth considering some Paypal alternatives such as [Stripe](https://stripe.com) or [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com). In the long run, their rates are fairly similar but you might end up saving some money somewhere along the line.

- Stripe charge 2.4% + 20p per transaction and their partner rates start around £20k.
- Braintree is a subsidiary of Paypal but, like Stripe, also charge 2.4% + 20p per transaction. However, the first £30k you make is free.

Oh, and I don't work for any of these companies, but have done research into payment gateways in the past for some product ideas.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The link you have provided for Braintree is no longer usable...

Comment: It works for me? Try https://www.braintreepayments.com/ if the link above isn't working